# Can't Navigate to a relative link on Angular with html5mode

Tags: angularjs

My website works fine when clicking through it, but when I try to navigate to a relative link path or refresh the link path always send me to my default route. e.g (http://app.somename.com/dashboard/start), have no idea what i can do.

Angular v.1.4.8

Comment: you need to specify you question

Comment: im try to acces for example to http://app.somename.com/dashboard/some setting this route in address bar but i always redirect to http://app.somename.com/dashboard/start

Comment: Can you send us what your links look like?

Comment: just try to remove "#" from my routes, i was working with http://app.somename.com/#/dashboard/some, i read about html5mode and i configured the serever, all works fine when clicking through, but when i acces to a route(e.g. http://app.somename.com/dashboard/route1) by address bar, always redirect me to http://app.somename.com/dashboard/start .

Comment: Are you able to show us what your routes config looks like to see if that has something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

What I can assume is happening to you is that you have written

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

In your routes.js file. What that line of code does is if angular can not find the entered URL it goes to your home page (the page you want it to go to). In my case the home page. Make sure you are typing the url correctly.

Comment: hi james, correct i have mi `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');` (dashboard in my case). i'm typing the url correctly but angular can not find my route and always redirect me to dashboard state.

Comment: @LeninCruzado can you post your route.js, either you are typing in the URL incorrectly or you have another issue. In my angular app the URL is: localhost:00000/#/home               That takes me to the home page if I want to visit the a more complex route like passing a parameter through the url that's a more complex situation. Is that what is causing the issue?

Comment: all works fine with "#" , but when i remove this with html5mode i cant acces to my routes typing the url on addres bar.

Comment: @LeninCruzado I started doing some digging, go ahead and review this web page. This will give you a good understanding on what you are trying to achieve https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase